# Remove duplicates from drop down

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a drop down menu on my form. The drop down shows a list of dates from my table but some values have duplicates (I cant delete the duplicates they need to stay)

I have the following SQL that I thought would only show unique values but it dont, any ideas whats gone wrong.

```
SELECT DISTINCT tblSourceData.ID, tblSourceData.[Competition Date]
FROM tblSourceData
ORDER BY tblSourceData.[Competition Date];
```

Answer (score 1):

I imagine each row has its own `ID` value, which makes every entry technically `distinct`. You could stop selecting the `ID`, then later (after something has been selected) look up which `ID` values correspond to a given `Competition Date`, if that information is still important.

Alternatively you could try `GROUP BY tblSourceData.[Competition Date]` instead of `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 1):

Can you show the code / tabledata?

Did you verify you are not adding some values to the drop down before fetching the data from the DB?

Answer (score 1):

If you just need "some" ID, then you can do:

```
SELECT 
    First(tblSourceData.ID) As ID
    tblSourceData.[Competition Date]
FROM 
    tblSourceData
GROUP BY
    tblSourceData.[Competition Date];
```